# Лицензия на иконки

Tags: icon, design, иконки, лицензирование

Здравствуйте,

Мы разрабатываем приложение на Android и недавно начали использовать иконки на Flaticon.com, но тут же столкнулись с вопросом лицензии. На Flaticon нужно указывать ссылку на автора или покупать premium доступ чтобы можно было использовать иконки в коммерческих целях.

У нас возникла идея создать свои иконки. Вопрос в следующем: если ми создадим такие же иконки или очень похожие на те что взяли на Flaticon.com, будут ли они считаться оригинальными и всё лицензионные права будут у нас, или это будет кража интеллектуальной собственности и нарушение лицензии?

Спасибо!

Comment: Ответ на этот вопрос зависит от квалификации вашего адвоката.

Answer (score 3):

**Can I use forever all the icons I download with the Premium account?**

**Yes, everytime you download a resource, it will include a document that grant you the unlimited right to use it forever.**

т.е. если вы заплатили 10 баксов, то все, что вы скачали с премиум-акком можете использовать вечность, лицензия идет на скачивание и продолжается навсегда.

вам жаль 10 баксов заплатить за месячный доступ и вместо этого вы готовы потратить время и ресурсы на переделку иконок? С таким подходом *не очень* хорошее у вас приложение получится.

Comment: Вопрос то ведь не об этом.

Comment: Имхо, это как раз тот случай, когда люди задают неправильный вопрос для нужного ответа, но если я не прав, то хотя бы на часть вопроса ответил

Answer (score 0):

По поводу flaticon есть [статья](https://vc.ru/18413-stolen-icons8). Если я правильно понял, за деньги которые вы платите, вы не получаете никаких прав на иконки. Т.е. используете на свой страх и риск.

Посмотрите пожалуйста эти [наборы](https://icons8.com/icon/new-icons/all). Тут понятных два вида лицензии (платная и **бесплатная**). Но самое главное - что вы можете заказать для себя недостающую иконку в нужном стиле, совершенно бесплатно.